# get the elements from a nested list in LISP

Tags: list, nested, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to figure out how to access the elements in a nested list in LISP. For example:

((3 (1 7) (((5)))) 4)

If I use dolist, i run into the brackets. Is there any method to just get the elements from the list?

Comment: Flatten the nested list.

Comment: @RainerJoswig How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly "access the elements in a nested list" means? random access by index of a sort? print them one by one?

Comment: ncoder: best you learn a bit Lisp, then you write a Lisp function. When you have a problem with that, then you post your code, some examples, what you have tried and the problems you have. It would be great if you put some effort into it. We already solved these problems, now it's your turn.

Comment: Basically I want to be able to get a new list of all the elements in the original list, but this time with no parenthesis. So for the list:

((3 (1 7) (((5)))) 4)

I want a new list that is:

(3 1 7 5 4)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a surprisingly subtle question!  It's in some ways the equivalent of asking: how do I get the nested elements of an HTML DOM, by specifying a pattern. (more on that aspect later)

If you just want to get the non-list elements as a sequence, e.g.

```
((3 (1 7) (((5)))) 4) --> 
(nth 3 (3 1 7 5 4)) -->
5
```

You can use the 'cheat' way: the `flatten` function in the CL alexandria library. (via [quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/))

```
(ql:quicklisp :alexandria)
(nth 3 (alexandria:flatten '((3 (1 7) (((5)))) 4)))
```

Which gives us the sought after,

```
5
```

But, the alexandrian function is simple enough that we can take a look at the source code itself:

```
(defun flatten (list)
  (cond 
    ((null list)
     nil)
    ((consp (car list))
     (nconc (flatten (car list)) (flatten (cdr list))))
    ((null (cdr list))
     (cons (car list) nil))
    (t
     (cons (car list) (flatten (cdr list))))))
```

As you can see, it's a recursive function -- at each level of recursion it asks the question: what is the object that I'm flattening?  If it's the empty list, return nil. I'm done!

Otherwise it has to be a non empty list.  If the first element of the list is also a list then flatten *that* and also flatten the `cdr` of the function argument list and concatenate the results.

If the first element is not a list and the second element is `'()`, that must mean we have a list with one element: return it.

The final case case, which exhausts our possibilities is that the first element in the list is an atom while the rest of the list is a list with at least one element.  In that case concatenate the first element with the results of a `flatten` performed on the rest of the list.

The fact that the description in English is so ponderous shows the power of recursion, (and also my own lack of fluency when describing it).

But there's actually another way your question could interpreted: if I have a list that looks something like: `((n1 (n2 n3) (((n4)))) n5)`  How do I get at `n2`, even if `n2` is itself a list?  Our previous recursive algorithm won't work -- it depends on n2 not being a list to know when to stop.  But, we *can* still use recursion and the very list we're searching as the basis for a pattern:

```
;; For each element in our pattern list look for a corresponding
;; element in the target, recursing on lists and skipping atoms that
;; don't match.
(defun extract-from-list (pattern target to-find)
  (dotimes (i (length pattern))
    (let ((ith-pattern (nth i pattern)))
      (cond
        ((consp ith-pattern)
          (let ((results
             (extract-from-list (nth i pattern)
                   (nth i target)
                   to-find)))
             (when results
               (return results))))
         (t
          (if (eq to-find ith-pattern)
             (return (nth i target))))))))
```

Note that,

```
(extract-from-list
 '((n1 (n2 n3) (((n4)))) n5)   ;; The pattern describing the list.
 '((3 (1 7) (((5)))) 4)        ;; The list itself.
 'n4)                          ;; which of the elements we want.
```

still returns the old answer:

```
 5
```

But,

```
(extract-from-list
 '((n1 (n2 n3) (n4)) n5)   ;; The pattern describing the list, note (n4) rather than (((n4))) 
 '((3 (1 7) (((5)))) 4)    ;; The list itself.
 'n4)                      ;; The element we want to pull from the list
```

Returns

```
 ((5))
```

Magic!  One of the aspects of Lisp that makes it so extraordinarily powerful.